# is there any idea so that i can't use os.path.join it creates errors

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying this code since yesterday it shows error mainly on os.path.join function in line no 15 and why train_face() have an error

```
import os
import  cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
people=['emily','emma','jim parson']


haar_cas=cv.CascadeClassifier('haar_face.xml')
# 

DIR=r'G:\opencv\faces'
features=[]
labels=[]
def train_face():
    for person in people:
        paths=os.path.join(DIR,people)
        label=people.index(person)
        for img in os.listdir(paths):
            img_path=os.path.join(paths,img)
            img_array=cv.imread(img_path)
            gray=cv.cvtColor(src=img_array,code=cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces_rect=haar_cas.detectMultiScale(gray,scalefactor=1.1,minNeighbor=1)
            for(x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
                faces_roi=gray[x:x+w,y:y+h]
                features.append(faces_roi)
                labels.append(label)

train_face()
print(f'length of the feature={len(features)}')
print(f'lenght of the labels={len(labels)}')
```

and the error arises as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\opencv\face_reconization.py", line 27, in <module>
    train_face()
  File "g:\opencv\face_reconization.py", line 15, in train_face
    paths=os.path.join(DIR,people)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\genericpath.py", line 153, in _check_arg_types     
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `os.path.join(DIR, person)` instead? Since you are iterating through `people` and binding each of them to `person`?

Comment: Why have you edited everything to be a string? Backticks and quotation marks are different things.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change

```
paths = os.path.join(DIR, people)
```

to

```
paths = os.path.join(DIR, person)
```

as the `people` variable you defined is indeed of type `list`.

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for `os.path.join()`.